# How to configure custom error page in a JSF portlet

Tags: portlet, jsf-1.2, custom-error-pages, jsr286

I have a JSF Portlet in a Portal page. I need to display a error page whenever an exception is thrown by any of the page bean methods. How can I do that?

I tried the below configuration in web.xml and it works for a servlet but not for a portlet.

```
<error-page>
  <exception-type>java.lang.Exception</exception-type>
  <location>/faces/exception.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
```

Right now whenever a page bean method throws exception, the application displays the first page.

I am using JSF 1.2 + Facelets and I don't have any additional 3rd party libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I extended the IBM FacesPortlet which we were using and added exception handling in processAction and render methods.